# How to create a new instance of a screen every time something happens

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create a new instance of my chat screen every time someone sends a message to a new person, i have a created a listview of buttons and it adds a button anytime someone sends a message to a new person but im trying to figure out how to direct it to a unique chat page that contains all the messages of the interaction. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code

```
class Chat(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        self.chatdestination = Label(
            text=firebase.get("/users/" + app.localId, 'first name') + " " + firebase.get('/users/' + app.localId,
                                                                                          'last name'),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}, size_hint=[0.8, 0.1], color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
            font_name="fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf")

        self.add_widget(self.chatdestination)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chat, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.localId = None
        self.messagebutton = Button(text="Send", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color= (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint= {"right": 1,"down": 1}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.messagebutton.bind(on_release = self.send_message)
        self.add_widget(self.messagebutton)


        self.messagetextinput = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8, hint_text= "Write a message", font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf", size_hint= [0.8, 0.1], pos_hint= {"left": 1,"down": 1})
        self.add_widget(self.messagetextinput)



        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)

    def on_key_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:
            self.send_message(None)



    def send_message(self, _):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        message = self.messagetextinput.text
        if len(message) > 0:
            database.child("messages").child(app.localId).update({self.localId: message})
            self.chatbubble = Button(text=self.messagetextinput.text, background_color = [0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0], background_normal = "",
                                      pos_hint= {"center_x": 1}, color = (1, 1, 1, 1), size_hint_y = None)
            self.chatbubble.size = self.chatbubble.texture_size

            self.ids.chatlayout.add_widget(self.chatbubble)
            self.ids.scrollview.scroll_to(self.chatbubble)
            self.messagetextinput.text = ""


            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)


            messages_list = []
            if app.localId not in messages_list:
                messages_list.append(app.localId)
                for id in messages_list:
                    messages_screen = self.manager.get_screen('messages')
                    messages_screen.messages_list.adapter.data.extend([])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into RecycleViews.
I think the best option may be to have a RecycleView that uses your 'Chat' as the viewclass.

Comment: can you explain more about it. the documentation is very limited